# Disable shipping method when total of products from certain category below $99

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to disable certain shipping method if the sum of the products from category "Pillows" is below $99 (it's some sort of a premium shipping active only if customer orders more than $99).

I have this piece of code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'unset_shipping_below_free', 10, 2 );
   
   function unset_shipping_below_free( $rates, $package ) {
   
   $categories = array('PILLOWS'); // Defined targeted product categories
   $threshold  = 99; // Defined threshold amount

   $cart       = WC()->cart;
   $cart_items = $cart->get_cart();
   
   
   //How to sum the value of Pillows in the cart?
   
    if ( $subtotal_pillows < $threshold ) {
        if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping:4'] ) ) {
             unset( $rates['free_shipping:4'] );
        } 
        if ( isset( $rates['flexible_shipping_single:5'] ) ) {
             unset( $rates['flexible_shipping_single:5'] );
        }
    }   
    return $rates;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to sum the value of the Pillows. Any help greatly appeciated

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'unset_shipping_below_free', 10, 2 );

function unset_shipping_below_free( $rates, $package ) {

  $categories = array('pillows'); // Defined targeted product categories slug
  $threshold  = 99; // Defined threshold amount

  $subtotal_pillows = 0;

  // Loop through all products in the Cart
  foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
      if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        $quantity      = $cart_item['quantity'];
        $line_subtotal = $cart_item['line_subtotal']; 
        $item_price    = $line_subtotal / $quantity;
        $subtotal_pillows = $subtotal_pillows+$item_price;
      }
  }
  //echo $subtotal_pillows; exit;

  //How to sum the value of Pillows in the cart?
  if ( $subtotal_pillows < $threshold ) {
    if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping:4'] ) ) {
         unset( $rates['free_shipping:4'] );
    } 
    if ( isset( $rates['flexible_shipping_single:5'] ) ) {
         unset( $rates['flexible_shipping_single:5'] );
    }
  }   
  return $rates;
}
```

Note:  $categories = array('pillows'); you should use category slug instead of category name for that you will got $subtotal_pillows properly category wise